# can we install sqlserver2005 before installing vs2005?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

I want to install sqlserver2005 on my server2003 machine. I heard that sqlserver2005 should be installed prior to visualstudio2005. Is it right or wrong?

Answer (score 2):

*can we install sqlserver2005 before installing vs2005?* - Yes

*i heard that sqlserver2005 should be installed prior to visualstudio2005. is it right or wrong?* - not necessarily, but it depends on what parts of SQL you are using.

Answer (score 2):

[This link](https://web.archive.org/web/20110829030802/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/Ingrid/archive/2006/02/03/68116.aspx) should give you the answer

In short

> The issue is that if you install
> Visual Studio first, SQL Server
> Express will be installed if there is
> not a local instance of SQL already
> installed. When you later attempt to
> install the SQL Server 2005
> workstation tools it will fail, but
> you are not blatantly alerted to that
> fact.

Answer (score 0):

They are independent of each other. It shouldn't make a difference which one you install first.